# Controlling Apple TV UI from a background running app

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

Could be possible use a background running app to control an apple tv?

I mean, using that app to execute the *basic commands* of an apple remote control.

My idea is to have a BLE device that sends commands to my apple tv, and then my background app translates those user commands (play, stop, volume up/down).

For example, imagine a tvOS app that receives commands from a micro:bit or Myo armband to control Netflix.

Thanks in advance!
Humberto

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

However, the question is quite broad, because you're speaking of receiving input from devices (with no specific issues), and then doing "basic commands" (again no specific issues there either).

You might try looking at a specific portion of what you'd like to do and then posting a question about any problems should any arise.

Good luck.

Comment: I would like to control the Apple TV (play, stop, next, ...) with a Myo Armband. Basically, translate myo gestures like fist, wave in, wave out to play, previous, and next video on the Apple TV

Comment: Your first stop should be Myo, which "officially" supports iOS and MacOS but not yet tvOS. However, it does support BLE Bluetooth, by which you can make some things happen.

Try those things out first, and come back if you have any issues. Again, good luck.